# Get default message for required validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, validation

I'd like to show the default error message for validation (e.g. required) with JavaScript.

The default message provided by the browser is fine (and it translates it automatically), I just want to trigger it programmatically with custom validation.

Is it possible to get the default error message provided by the browser?

Comment: ooh interesting question

Comment: possible to get the ... Did it mean trigger validation message?

Comment: for me this is not possible, you can't change the behaviour of native form validation

Comment: I am not sure of a way to get the default error messages provided by the browser, what I  know is with reactjs you can preventDefault and that way the browser lets you specify custom validation on your form elements and display messages these messages to the user

Comment: @NahashonNjenga Yeah, that's how we do it right now but coming up with translations for these things is annoying :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (// your check)
        this.setCustomValidity('Error');
    else
        this.setCustomValidity('');
});
```

so when you submit the form the custom validity message will be show by the browser

EDIT:

Example on 'stackoverflow'

```
document.querySelector('#search > div > input').setCustomValidity('Hello')
```

if your click on search button you will have

[image]

To get the validation message of the browser you can do this:

```
document.querySelector('#search > div > input').validationMessage
```

Comment: I tried that on this page and it didn't work: `document.querySelector('#wmd-input').setCustomValidity('Error');`

Comment: I updated my post, after you set the validity message you need to submit the form to show the error message :)

Comment: In modern browser you can use this 'document.querySelector('#search > div > input').reportValidity()'

Comment: But, I don't want a custom error message, I want the default error message provided by the browser.

Comment: You can use element.validationMessage ( check my edit )

Comment: Thanks! Gonna try this when I can =)